# Hosting a WCF Service In A WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I am quite new to WCF. How do you host a WCF service in a WinForm? Obviously the service would only be available while the form is open but this is exactly what I am after.

There are only a few (poor) examples of doing it which I have found and even the MSDN starts talking about hosting one in a WinForm but then goes and implements it in a Windows Service.

Comment: What about this one? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx, first google hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open your app, and place something like this in your form:

1. Create your WCF interface

   ```
   <ServiceContract()>
   Public Interface IyourInterface
   <OperationContract()>
   Function asyouwant ....
   ```
2. Create the class that implements it

   ```
   Public Class clsYourClass
   Implements IyourInterface
   ```
3. Instantiate it from your winforms app.

   (This is vb.net)

   ```
   Dim oYourService As ServiceHost
   Dim oYourBinding As New System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding 
      ' Or WSHttpBinding ... configure as you want
   Dim aAddress As Uri()
   aAddress=   New Uri() {New Uri("http://localhost:port")}
   oYourService = New ServiceHost(GetType(clsYourClass), aAddress)
   oYourService.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IyourInterface), oYourBinding, "myWinformService.svc")
   oYourService.Open()
   ```

4 - Try this: http://localhost:port/myWinformService.svc

Answer (score -1):

Simple service for example..

**IService**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Calculate(int price, int Qty);
}
```

**Service**

```
public class Service : IService
    {
        public string Calculate(int price, int Qty)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(price * Qty);
        }
    }
```

**Consume service by user**

Go to Add Service reference option and discover the service. Add the service. Now the service displays in solution explorer.

```
http://localhost/WCFServiceSample/Service.svc
```

To check in web browser.

**Usage in Application**

```
using WindowsFormsApplicationWCF.ServiceReference1;

   Service1Client obj = new Service1Client();

   private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string result;
       result = obj.Calculate(Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtQty.Text));

        lblresult.Text = "The total price is" + result;
    }
```

Check these links for you reference,

[Hosting WCF service inside a Windows Forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231867/hosting-wcf-service-inside-windows-form)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/consuming-wcf-service-in-windows-application/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx